# Are any events generated when stylus proximity is detected?

Tags: xinput, touch-screen

I trying to configure my laptop's touchscreen + stylus so that the touch device is turned off when the stylus is detected, so that I can rest my hand on the screen while writing. I can write a script that does this by checking for 'proximity' in the xinput output, but this script would have to check a few times per second to have a good response time.

I was wondering whether the stylus proximity generates an event that can be captured somehow to avoid watching the xinput output all the time... I don't see anything in acpi_listen. Any hints?

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
STYLUS_ID=11 # replace with ID or name of your stylus
TOUCH_ID=9 # replace with ID or name of your touch screen

xinput test -proximity "$STYLUS_ID" |
    while read line; do
        if [[ $line == *out* ]]; then
            xinput enable "$TOUCH_ID"
        else
            xinput disable "$TOUCH_ID"
        fi
    done
```

Instead of polling the state of the stylus, it relies on the option `test` of `xinput`, which enters an endless loop displaying `proximity` events for the device. From `xinput`'s man page:

```
    test [-proximity] device
           Register all extended events from device and enter an endless loop
           displaying events received. If the -proximity is given, ProximityIn
           and ProximityOut are registered.
```